# Why isn't this driver install working (sudo code)?

Tags: drivers, software-installation

I have a soundcard that I'd like to use and I've been trying to install it and being a new Ubuntu user, I get about half way through this in the Terminal and it stops cooperating with me... See the link (soundcard hyperlink) but basically what I have here:

I do the following and it works:

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

svn co https://line6linux.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/line6linux

Change to the directory

```
cd line6linux/driver/trunk
```

Time to build from the source but first make sure you have the latest build and headers

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install linux-headers
```

Then after this point it says must specify file to install. Not sure how to do this or what it means.

Then, running `make` gives the following output:

> ./set_revision.sh ./set_revision.sh: 9: test: https://line6linux.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/line6linux/driver/trunk: unexpected operator make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/build CONFIG_LINE6_USB=m SUBDIRS=/home/nick/line6linux/driver/trunk modules make[1]: Entering directory /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-29-generic-pae' CC [M] /home/nick/line6linux/driver/trunk/audio.o /home/nick/line6linux/driver/trunk/audio.c: In function ‘line6_init_audio’: /home/nick/line6linux/driver/trunk/audio.c:30:57: error: ‘THIS_MODULE’ undeclared (first use in this function) /home/nick/line6linux/driver/trunk/audio.c:30:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in make[2]: *** [/home/nick/line6linux/driver/trunk/audio.o] Error 1 make[1]: *** [*module*/home/nick/line6linux/driver/trunk] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-29-generic-pae' make: * [default] Error 2

This is in Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

Another thing, semi related. Cut, copy, paste? Seems like it's different from program to program. I was in the terminal and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> in Firefox and it won't paste. But in terminal it will paste. I'm confused.

---

Here is what it's giving me after I hit "Make": nick@NickUbuntu:~/line6linux/driver/trunk$ make
./set_revision.sh
./set_revision.sh: 9: test: https://line6linux.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/line6linux/driver/trunk: unexpected operator
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic-pae/build CONFIG_LINE6_USB=m SUBDIRS=/home/nick/line6linux/driver/trunk modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-29-generic-pae'
  CC [M]  /home/nick/line6linux/driver/trunk/audio.o
/home/nick/line6linux/driver/trunk/audio.c: In function ‘line6_init_audio’:
/home/nick/line6linux/driver/trunk/audio.c:30:57: error: ‘THIS_MODULE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/nick/line6linux/driver/trunk/audio.c:30:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[2]: *** [/home/nick/line6linux/driver/trunk/audio.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/nick/line6linux/driver/trunk] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory`/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-29-generic-pae'
make: *** [default] Error 2

Looks like these folks also had similar problems:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1163608&page=3

Comment: You might try running `make clean`, then run `make`. If you get the same error, say so. If this fixes your problem, finish the job by running `sudo make install`.

Comment: Tried that and it's giving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that [this](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-install-line6-guitarport-in-ubuntu.html) is what you're installing.

The problem is that you need to specify the version of linux-headers to install. If you run  `apt-cache search linux-headers`, you'll see there are many different versions. To install the correct version, run

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

This will automatically install the linux-headers for your particular system. After this point, the rest of the commands (`make`, etc) should work fine.

And regarding copying/pasting in the terminal versus elsewhere: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> copies text you've selected in the terminal, whereas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> copies text you've selected elsewhere (e.g., Firefox/Chrome). Similarly, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste in the terminal and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste elsewhere.

Comment: Here is what it's giving me after I hit "Make":

Comment: Did you run the command I wrote in this post to the linux-headers? If so, did it work?

Comment: Here's what I ended up with after trying that:

Comment: Please post the output. It didn't show up.

Comment: I tried it after make clean then ran make and got the same errors as above again. EDIT: This forum is difficult for me to navigate. I try to hit Enter to start a new line etc and it just saves it. So sorry for the messiness. Not intentional by any means. Also, I tried to post the code and I think it went over the character limit. But same errors as above.

Comment: I also have http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12201497#post12201497 this link running. I was able to post more coherently there due to a forum format that I'm more familiar with.